# Can I have DataMapper and ActiveRecord use different database adapters in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, datamapper

I have a Rails application which has been using DataMapper. I am about to convert it to use ActiveRecord. If possible, I would like to do this one model (or group of models) at a time.

Right now, I can't even get the app to boot because the two ORMs seem to require different adapters.

If `database.yml` specifies the adapter `mysql`, `bundler/rubygems_integration.rb` raises:

```
Please install the mysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter` (mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

If it specifies `mysql2`, `activesupport/dependencies` raises:

```
cannot load such file -- dm-mysql2-adapter (LoadError)
```

I tried creating a separate environment for ActiveRecord with the `mysql2` adapter, then using `establish_connection` from an individual model I want to convert first, but the app still won't boot.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: Update: I never got them running side-by-side; I just did a massive replacement in which everything was broken for a while. :( Good luck to anyone else attempting this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this particular issue seems to be to give DataMapper its database connection info as a `uri` option, while ActiveRecord will use the connection specified by the adapter, username, root, and host options.

```
defaults: &defaults
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password: somePassword
  host: localhost

development: &development
  database: myapp_dev
  uri: mysql://localhost/myapp_dev?user=root&password=somePassword
  <<: *defaults

test:
  database: myapp_test
  uri: mysql://localhost/myapp_test?user=root&password=somePassword
  <<: *defaults
production:
  database: myapp_dev
  <<: *defaults
```

Getting the two ORMs to play nicely together will involve a lot of other issues, though. Personally I've given up and am just ripping DataMapper right out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. This code needs to run after your ActiveRecord model has been loaded.

```
db_settings = YAML::load_file("#{ROOT_PATH}/config/database_settings_for_active_record.yml")
db_config = db_settings[Rails.env]
spec = Hash.new
[:adapter, :host, :username, :password, :pool, :database].each { |x| spec.merge!(x => db_config[x.to_s]) }
YourModel.establish_connection(spec)
```

database_settings_for_active_record.yml would contain something like:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
  pool: 5
  database: my_db
```